# Value of Lagrangian Multiplier

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have a two dimensional optimization problem of the form
$$
v = \max_{x,y} f(x,y)+g(x,y)
$$
Both $g,f$ are concave and continuously differentiable.
Assume the solution can be reached by first order conditions and $(x^*,y^*)$ is unique.

And $v>0$, $g(x^*,y^*)<0$.

Now I modify the problem to 
$$
u = \max_{x,y} f(x,y)
$$
s.t.
$$
g(x,y)=0
$$

Then, following the lagrangian method, I need to solve a new problem 
$$
\max \mathcal{L} = f(x,y)+\lambda g(x,y)
$$

My question is, is there any conclusive property regarding the value of multiplier $\lambda$? Say whether it is greater than 1 or not?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, the Lagrange multiplier method does not necessarily find *extrema* of the Lagrangian, they are often saddle points. Accordingly, I think you may need some assumptions about $f$ and $g$ (e.g. that they are both concave) to get a result like the one you seem to want.

Comment: @lan Thanks! Yes, I assumed both $f$ and $g$ are concave.